# Setting editable integer column in TableView in javafx-2.2

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I'm new to javafx and I trying to create editable integer column.

I've read http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/ and http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm
and still have big question about working with integer properties.

I've created a model that contains IntegerProperty. IntegerProperty is descendant of *ObservableValue[Number]*. TableColumn is invariant over field type, so I was forced to make this column be typed as *TableColumn[MyModel,Number]*. Than I need to create cellFactory that allows editing integer cell. *TextFieldTableCell(IntegerStringConverter)* is supposed to fulfill this aim but IntegerStringConverter is typed as *StringConverter[Integer]* not StringConverter[Number] and TextFieldTableCell is also invariant towards value type.

So I get conflict:

- IntegerProperty require Number type
- StringConverter provide Integer type
- TableColumn is invariant and require both types to match

How was TableColumn supposed to be used with this restrictions?

Comment: +1 for "How was TableColumn supposed to be used with this restrictions?"

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had to do something similar once using javafx.beans.property.adapter.JavaBeanIntegerPropertyBuilder to build a javafx.beans.property.adapter.JavaBeanIntegerProperty.

I suggest you use this adapter class instead of IntegerProperty. I am kind of tied up now but I will implement it and edit this answer ASAP.

Comment: I study this doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/property/adapter/JavaBeanIntegerProperty.html

It says that JavaBeanIntegerProperty is descendant of ObservableValue[Number] as well as IntegerProperty

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar problem when using ScalaFX 1.0.0.M2 for Scala 2.10.  I had been using:

```
private val portColumn = new TableColumn[Model, Int] {
    text = "Port"
    cellValueFactory = {
      _.value.port
    }
  }
```

In order to solve this problem, I changed it to:

```
private val portColumn = new TableColumn[Model, Number] {
    text = "Port"
    cellValueFactory = {
      _.value.port.delegate
    }
  }
```

Also, and **very important**, I had to upgrade to ScalaFX 1.0.0.*M4* for Scala 2.10.

I haven't made the cell editable, so I'll try that out and let you know how it goes.